# merge multiple rss feeds

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, rss-reader

I think it's very basic question but i want to know how to merge multiple rss feeds and display the merged feed

As feeds are from multiple sources, i have to remove duplicate feeds and display only relevant information.

I am using asp.net(VS2010).

Some of other posts:
[Merging Multiple RSS feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499101/merging-multiple-rss-feeds)

[merge rss feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148/merge-rss-feeds)

I don't want to use yahoo pipes.

Please let me know how can i do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feeds are in xml format. So you have to merge the contents of the "channel" nodes of your rss feeds. For this look at this link [How to merge two XmlDocuments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440073/how-to-merge-two-xmldocuments-in-c-sharp)

Please also see this: [Multiple channels in a single RSS xml - is it ever appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798863/multiple-channels-in-a-single-rss-xml-is-it-ever-appropriate)